# Sony Enterprise API version on Xperia Z3 Compact

Tags: android, sony, mdm, sony-xperia

The description for Android App "Airwatch Sony Service" on the Google Play Store, mentions "Currently, devices with Sony enterprise API version 3-5 have been certified by AirWatch."
Would any of the developers or Sony staff know what version of the Sony Enterprise API is there on the Xperia Z3 Compact(D5803)?

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: first of all, versions are like tags, serials,ids,verifiers,notifiers or whatever you can call it..Second of all, if they did not or could not why will they even put it out there? thirdly, its a notifier for users, to note even if they can not know-(which is never a possibility)lastly, what's up with that question..

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `Settings -> Apps -> All` to see if there is an app called "Sony Enterprise API," or something similar.  If there is, you can tap on it to see the currently installed version number.

Here's a YouTube video demonstrating how to get to the "All" apps list:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUR9JK7pkz0

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest posting your question to https://android.stackexchange.com/, as this type of question is much more suitable for that community.

Answer (score 0):

Xperia Z3 line has enhanced support for Enterprise API - version 6.